# Microsoft Visio OLE Automation error logging

Tags: java, swt, visio, ole-automation

I am working with OleAutomation Java APIs provided by SWT(Standard Widget Toolkit) to manipulate Visio documents. We have generated Java wrappers over automation APIs using OleAutomation calls. for e.g :(shape delete)

```
/**
 * COM Id: 11
 */

public void Delete() {
    //Invoke
    Variant varInputArray[] = new Variant[0];
    Variant varResult = oleAutomation.invoke(11, varInputArray);
    for (Variant _varItr : varInputArray) {
        _varItr.dispose();
    }
    if(varResult !=null)
    {
        varResult.dispose();
    }
}
```

I am facing a peculiar problem when calling this delete from a certain place in the application logic. On a page I place a shape and call delete. For odd numbered calls the delete is successful and the varResult returns VT_EMPTY(1st,3rd,5th.... time call). For even numbered calls (I place the shape again on the page and call -2nd,4th 6th etc) the varResult returns "null" which indicates failure. Now I need to understand what's going wrong with even numbered call. Is there some kind of logging facility in Visio Automation framework which can log the reason for failure ?

Comment: I looked into the oleAutomation.invoke() call from SWT code base.An exception with description " requested operation is presently disabled" is thrown for the failing delete operation. Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting shapes backwards. I.e. iterate collection backwards when deleting shapes.
That means, instead of:

```
shapes = Page.Shapes;
foreach (shape : shapes)
{
    if (xxx)
        shape.Delete()
}
```

Try this

```
shapes = Page.Shapes;
for (int i = shapes.Count; i > 0; --i)
{
    if (xxx)
        shapes[i].Delete()
}
```

Means, Visio has a bit "naive" collection management, so deleting items from collection while iterating over it may put you in troubles, and should be done carefully, like one would do for an array.

Alternatively, you can first select all shapes to delete and then delete them in one shot:

```
shapes = Page.shapes;
sel = Page.CreateSelection(visSelTypeEmpty);

foreach (shape : shapes)
{
    if (xxx)
        sel.Select(shape, visSelect);
}

sel.Delete();
```

Comment: I am aware of this approach. In my particular case I am deleting a single shape. This is a connector shape["conx" shape] between two shapes ."conx" shape is connected to two block shapes which triggers a server call and the server returns a failure status for the operation. Because of the failure I delete this "conx" shape on the Visio page. Delete is now successful. Now I again repeat the action i.e. drop this "conx" shape on the Visio page and hook it to the block shapes. The server again returns a failure status but my attempt to delete the "conx" shape this time around fails.

Comment: Okay, if you are aware of that then maybe the problem is elsewhere.